TextField not changing foreground color in iOS 17.4
Given the following view:
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Example", text: self.$text)
            Text(self.text)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundStyle(self.text.count % 2 == 0 ? .red : .blue)
    }
}

When typing text, I would expect the foreground color of the TextField to change between red and blue. However, it does not on iOS 17.4 (it does on iOS 16.x and iOS 17 up to 17.2). Is there a new way to achieve this behaviour or is it potentially a bug in iOS 17.3+?

Unrelated but you can use count.isMultiple(of: 2) instead of count % 2 == 0

@JoakimDanielson can you check https://github.com/kerrmarin/text-field-swiftui? Not sure why you are unable to reproduce.

Either I made a mistake or something else interfered since I pasted the code into an existing project but now I can't reproduce anymore.

Running on an iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.4, the Text was changing color, but the TextField was not. This may be because, the TextField is the source of changes to the state variable text (as text is entered) and this doesn't seem to trigger indirect changes to itself.
A workaround is to use a separate state variable for the color and update it in an .onChange handler:
@State private var text: String = ""
@State private var fgColor = Color.red

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Example", text: $text)
        Text(text)
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundStyle(fgColor)
    .onChange(of: text) { oldVal, newVal in
        fgColor = newVal.count % 2 == 0 ? .red : .blue
    }
}


Thanks, the color was just a simplification of my problem but your suggestion was the basis of a solution to the more specific problem I was having.
